# Getting current OpenGL context on OS X

Tags: qt, opengl, opencl

currently I am trying to get OpenCL<->OpenGL interop capabilities to work. My code to get a shared context:

```
cl_int error = 0;
CGLContextObj glContext = CGLGetCurrentContext();

CGLShareGroupObj shareGroup = CGLGetShareGroup(glContext);
cl_context_properties props[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE, (cl_context_properties)shareGroup,
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)this->_clPlatform,
    0
};

context =  clCreateContext(props, 1, &this->_clDevice, NULL, NULL, &error);
```

This code fails during `clCreateContext` with `INVALID_VALUE` error. I know that `_clDevice` is valid since with my OpenCL-Only-Context it works fine, but I found out that CGLGetCurrentContext() always return `0`. I think this the "invalid value" but why is it always `0`? Do I have to create a context manually? I am using it as part of a C++/Qt program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)this->_clPlatform
```

completely. It worked for me using only `CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE`.